# How to count characters in DOS text file including line ending?

Tags: java

I'm trying count the number of characters in a text file. However, I can only count the letters and whitespace, not \r\n at the end of the line. How can I include it?
The function below counts the number of lines, words, and characters in a file.

```
    public static void Count(String FILENAME, int n) throws IOException {
    inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
    String currentLine; //= inFile.readLine();
    while ((currentLine=inFile.readLine()) != null) {
        lines[n]++;
        bytes[n]+=currentLine.length();
        bytes[n]++;
        String[] WORDS = currentLine.split(" "); // split the string into sub-string by whitespace
        // to separate each words and store them into an array
        words[n] = words[n] + WORDS.length;
        if (currentLine.length()==0)
            words[n]--;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to utilize Character Streams instead of Line-oriented Streams since character streams give you one character each time you call readLine().

```html
public static void Count(String FILENAME, int n) throws IOException {
    inFile = new FileReader(FILENAME);
    char currentCharacter;
    int numCharacters = 0;

    String currentLine = "";
    while ((currentCharacter=inFile.readLine()) != null){
      if(currentCharacter == '\n')
      {
         lines[n]++;
         bytes[n]+=currentLine.length();
         bytes[n]++;
         String[] WORDS = currentLine.split(" "); 
         words[n] = words[n] + WORDS.length;
         if (currentLine.length()==0)
            words[n]--;
      }
      currentCharacter=inFile.readLine();
      currentLine += currentCharacter;
      numCharacters ++;
   }
```

And then the sum would be stored in numCharacters. To retain the ability to count lines and bytes and such, you could have a String line declared before the loop and concatenate each character to the end of it in the loop. Once you hit a \n, you know that you have one line in the line variable. Then u could increment line[n] by one, increase bytes[n] by line.length(), etc.

source of info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Answer (score 0):

for counting  \r\n use read() method.

readLine() method Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

Returns:
    A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: but read() returns an integer, I do need the string to split the line into words